# Retrieve encrypted data from config but the data is Garbled text

Tags: magento-1.9, core-config-data

I'm trying to retrieve a **encrypted data** from config data by external script,

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('memory_limit', '8192M');

require_once('app/Mage.php');
$app = Mage::app();

$secure_secret = Mage::getModel('core/encryption')->decrypt(Mage::getStoreConfig(
                   'payment/migs_hosted/secure_secret',
                   Mage::app()->getStore()
               )); 


var_dump( $secure_secret)."<BR>";

?>
```

But the output is **Garbled** text **`"string(24) "� �m��zJ}�G�H6��R��6""`** .

Do anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: The encrypted data has encrypted from magento. Are you sure ? I think,  problem is with encrypted data. It may be encryption type is different. Magento use `base64_encode` to encrypt the data.

Comment: @zedBlackbeard i search in DB config data, the value is hk+CfgNr0THg8/+KmZb6T6EdLdEU89mT1fkfySu7Qis= , but i can't decode it by base64_decode

Comment: If you are using third-party secret key. you can not decrypt from magneto.